# How do I get the ID text of the checked item in the select element?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the ID text of the checked item in the select element?

I need it to change the color of a text, so for example one id could be "red".

```
<script>
function add(){
    var str = document.getElementById("item");
    str.style.color = ;
}
</script>
```

Basically I named the id's in the option's as "red", "yellow" and "blue" so I need something to get those id's as text and add it after `str.style.color =`.

Comment: please post your code and ask for help, we're not here to write code for you but to help you improve your already existing code. No hate

Comment: @OrangeOrange posted

Comment: thank you, but we need the html also to fully understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using jquery.

In this "my_select" is the selector in this. you can get that full element by **:selected**

```
$("#my_select").change(function() {
var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
});
```

you can get full element by **this** keyword. try to by log

```
$("#my_select").change(function() {
console.log(this);
});
```

after getting full element u can do anything with it like changing color or bold etc.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: @inzamam you're using jQuery here, if user673763 is new to coding he won't know how to make it work

Comment: @OrangeOrange I don't know how to use jQuery in fact

Comment: @user673763 I am also new to js
but u can find it alternate solution to this Jquery code
by 
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ f